# What is vshub.exe in the system tray?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 14. Now I have a new app `VsHub` in the system tray / notification area. What is it? I tried clicking and right-clicking on it, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

According to Visual Studio Blog site (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/08/18/visual-studio-14-ctp-3-released.aspx?PageIndex=2&wa=wsignin1.0):

> "The Visual Studio Hub is an executable that supports multi-tool
>   communication across the VS family of apps, service
>   composition/isolation, and data/compute outside of the Visual Studio
>   process."

Comment: I'm so glad this question wasn't closed. Some people are a bit too quick to close questions that don't strictly include code, even though this question is on-topic.

Comment: It load my system on 100%, how i can remove VSHub ?

Comment: Here's already some info on how to get rid of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452435/how-do-i-disable-vshub-exe-in-the-system-tray

Answer (score 5):

I solved stopping the folliwing Windows service:

**Visual Studio Standard Collector Service**

After stop, my pc is returned to work correclty, without strange load.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

I have a slightly more direct solution to this.  It's relatively trivial to locate where VSHub.exe and its cohorts are on your hard disk.  Just go into that directory, take ownership of all the .exe files contained in it, and for each of them use "Right Click" / "Properties" / Security, and add an ACL that denies execute permissions to everyone.

Problem solved.  You will need to re-do this every time you update VS 2015, but on my low power laptop, I simply can't afford the resources to keep all these unnecessary tools running.  VS 2015 runs just fine without them: I can edit, build and debug programs without any problems at all.

Sure, I may be missing some of the more esoteric features of VS 2015, but for my use case [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it)