# How to disable Diagnostic Tools?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2022

When debugging a C# application in Visual Studio 2015, **Diagnostic Tools** starts automatically. I unchecked both checkboxes in **Select Tools**, but it doesn't seem to completely disable it.

How do I turn it off (and on again later)?

Comment: Also true for MFC.

Answer (score 416, accepted):

If you want to disable the feature altogether you can currently do so from Tools → Options → Debugging → General → Enable Diagnostics Tools while debugging

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I needed to restart VS before change took affect

Comment: I often accidently click the "elapsed time" link. So I just disable this link by unticking "Show elapsed time PerfTip while debugging"

Comment: For me it worked without restarting VS after changing the setting in Tools -> Options.

Comment: @CrazyTim Thanks! This is what I basically wanted to disable since it's mostly completely irrelevant but quite distracting when debugging.