# How to fix "Internal Diagnostics Hub Exception" in VS 2015 Update 1?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've just updated to Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, and I'm getting the error whenever I start debugging:

> Internal Diagnostics Hub Exception. See log for more details.

[image: Screenshot of error message]

How do I fix this, or disable the error?

I don't know which log file I should check. In `ActivityLog.xml`, the last entry is of yesterday, so that doesn't contain anything useful. Next, I know there is a logfile of MEF (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.err`), but that's empty. How to investigate this?

Comment: Btw, based on the following SO question, I was able to disable the Diagnostics Tools. Although that prevents the problem from occurring, it doesn't solve my problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904929/how-to-disable-diagnostic-tools

Comment: Sadly none of the fixes below worked for me.  I had to disable Diagnostics to remove message. Uncheck Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Diagnostics Tools while debugging http://stackoverflow.com/a/31904957/891394

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.html` was missing from `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\DiagnosticsHub\WebViews\`. After I copied over the file from a coworker, the error was fixed ;)

I've put the file in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tiesmaster/8d5187a800e1d5e2ecf0), in case you want it.

Comment: Came across this error when installed VS2015 Update #3. Your file fixed my problem. Cheers.

Comment: Good to hear it helped :)

Answer (score 12):

I dug into the the Visual Studio logs to understand what was happening (`C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml`). In mine, the messages were something like this:

```
  <entry>
    <record>846</record>
    <time>2016/07/22 01:07:20.351</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>847</record>
    <time>2016/07/22 01:07:20.367</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]</description>
    <guid>{2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>848</record>
    <time>2016/07/22 01:07:20.374</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]Source: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition&apos; Description: An exception was thrown while initializing part &quot;Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptContexts.TypeScriptProjectProvider&quot;.&#x000D;&#x000A;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: An exception was thrown while initializing part &quot;Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptContexts.TypeScriptProjectProvider&quot;. ---&gt; System.IO.IOException: Error while reading file: &apos;typescriptServices.js&apos; from location: &apos;C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\VGMMC3GX.G57\8WMQ7NH1.KPN\ffb2b475\00c96cd3_2ec7d101&apos;. ---&gt; System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file &apos;C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\VGMMC3GX.G57\8WMQ7NH1.KPN\ffb2b475\00c96cd3_2ec7d101\typescriptServices.js&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptServices.FileHelpers.ReadFile(String filePath)&#x000D;&#x000A;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptServices.FileHelpers.ReadFile(String filePath)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptServices.FileHelpers.GetToolsVersionFromFile(IUserSettingsProvider userSettingsProvider)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptContexts.TypeScriptProjectProvider..ctor(SVsServiceProvider serviceProvider, ScriptIdFactory scriptIdFactory, IUserSettingsProvider userSettingsProvider, IProjectCompilationSettingsProvider projectCompilationSettingsProvider)&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)&#x000D;&#x000A;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass15_0.&lt;GetExportedValueHelper&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportElement(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, Func`3 lazyFactory)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.&lt;CreateValue&gt;b__10_0(RuntimeImport import)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass53_0.&lt;CreateExport&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.NetFxAdapters.MefV1ExportProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass12_0.&lt;UnwrapExport&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.GetExportedValueCore()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass12_0`1.&lt;CreateStronglyTypedLazyOfT&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage.SetupGlobalCommandHandlers()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass53_0.&lt;CreateExport&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.NetFxAdapters.MefV1ExportProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass12_0.&lt;UnwrapExport&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.GetExportedValueCore()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass12_0`1.&lt;CreateStronglyTypedLazyOfT&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage.SetupGlobalCommandHandlers()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass53_0.&lt;CreateExport&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.NetFxAdapters.MefV1ExportProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass12_0.&lt;UnwrapExport&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.GetExportedValueCore()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass12_0`1.&lt;CreateStronglyTypedLazyOfT&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage.SetupGlobalCommandHandlers()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass53_0.&lt;CreateExport&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.NetFxAdapters.MefV1ExportProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass12_0.&lt;UnwrapExport&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.GetExportedValueCore()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass12_0`1.&lt;CreateStronglyTypedLazyOfT&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage.SetupGlobalCommandHandlers()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)System.IO.IOException: Error while reading file: &apos;typescriptServices.js&apos; from location: &apos;C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\VGMMC3GX.G57\8WMQ7NH1.KPN\ffb2b475\00c96cd3_2ec7d101&apos;. ---&gt; System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file &apos;C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\VGMMC3GX.G57\8WMQ7NH1.KPN\ffb2b475\00c96cd3_2ec7d101\typescriptServices.js&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptServices.FileHelpers.ReadFile(String filePath)&#x000D;&#x000A;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptServices.FileHelpers.ReadFile(String filePath)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptServices.FileHelpers.GetToolsVersionFromFile(IUserSettingsProvider userSettingsProvider)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptContexts.TypeScriptProjectProvider..ctor(SVsServiceProvider serviceProvider, ScriptIdFactory scriptIdFactory, IUserSettingsProvider userSettingsProvider, IProjectCompilationSettingsProvider projectCompilationSettingsProvider)&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file &apos;C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\VGMMC3GX.G57\8WMQ7NH1.KPN\ffb2b475\00c96cd3_2ec7d101\typescriptServices.js&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\VGMMC3GX.G57\8WMQ7NH1.KPN\ffb2b475\00c96cd3_2ec7d101\typescriptServices.js&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptServices.FileHelpers.ReadFile(String filePath)</description>
    <guid>{2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}</guid>
    <hr>80131500</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>849</record>
    <time>2016/07/22 01:07:21.945</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral](null)</description>
    <guid>{2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}</guid>
    <hr>80131500</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>850</record>
    <time>2016/07/22 01:07:21.951</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]</description>
    <guid>{2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}</guid>
    <hr>80131500</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

And then, I realized that TypeScript support should be broken.

Just [installing TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593), closing Visual Studio and then opening your project again will solve your problem. The message will disappear.

Comment: That solve my problem - SO is not built for it but there are multiple right answer to this question.

Answer (score 9):

To enable the logs for the diagnostic tools, add the following registry keys

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\DiagnosticsHub\LogLevel  
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\DiagnosticsHub\LogDirectory
```

For LogLevel you can use one of the following strings "All", "Info", "Debug", "Warning", "Error" (In your case I would use All to better see what is happening). As for LogDirectory it is a directory of your choice "C:\Logs". When your done, don't forget to delete these keys as the diagnostic tools logging is pretty system intensive.

We try to only prompt message boxes in unexpected cases (normal errors are only shown as an error in the tool window and never through a message box), so this sounds like an issue with a 3rd party app or some weird upgrade issue. You should be able to search for "Error ---" in the logs and see what the root cause is. Feel free to post the error here or PM me and I would be happy to help (Note: I work on the Diagnostic Tools team)

Feel free to also post the issue at: https://connect.microsoft.com/
Each issue that is received there gets turned into a bug and assigned to the corresponding team.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this immediately when I'm in the office in less than an hour. I'll post my result here, if I have anything useful ;)

I didn't put in a connect issue, but I did use the "Report Problem" from within Visual Studio. I did that like 2 weeks ago. I hoped that that would end up with your team, but maybe that still in the process.

I'm quite sure this is an upgrade issue, since it started to happen after I upgrade to Update 1. Though, it must be related to my environment, or tools, because none of my colleagues have this problems.

Comment: Ok, I've enabled logging. There are a couple log entries of level Error. I've posted the full log file [here](https://gist.github.com/tiesmaster/8bc851745f650696aa59), but probably it's the "HttpClient cannot be null", which [turns up](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/92224afe-624a-4337-a523-3af3dcc8dda4/diagnostic-could-not-be-started?forum=vsdebug) if I search for that specific problem. I won't be able to uninstall and install VS in the next couple of days, but when I do, I'll post the results here.

Comment: After I noticed [this](https://gist.github.com/tiesmaster/8bc851745f650696aa59#file-devenv-11460-log-L122) error, I copied over `PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.html` from a coworkers computer, and that fixed the problem ^_^

Comment: I have enabled the logging, but the worst entry I get is 1 Warning, that the "Bridge collection session is shutting down". A Warning does not explain the total failure?

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

1. Stop the VSHub.exe process
2. Delete the files in %TMP%\VsHub\
3. Restart the "Visual Studio Standard Collector Service"

Inspired by this post:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3038181/internal-diagnostics-hub-exception

Comment: This worked for me but I did not even have to delete the files mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue on one of my installations (an upgrade from `Update 1` versus a clean ISO install of the `Update 2 RC` bits which works). It should be noted my installation was also missing the ScriptedHost.dll assembly which I had to manually copy over from the working system :\

```
Debug --- ApplicationPathService --- Hub application path is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\DiagnosticsHub'
Debug --- Scripted Control (PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.manifest.json) --- Initializing the ScriptedControl with manifest file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\DiagnosticsHub\WebViews\PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.manifest.json'. Base directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions'
Debug --- Scripted Control (PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.manifest.json) --- Menu command service is provided for manifest 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\DiagnosticsHub\WebViews\PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.manifest.json'.
Debug --- Document ('C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Temp\Report20160308-1527.diagsession') --- Graph Update data packet 1 sent (size: 1073)
Debug --- DataWarehouseInstance --- Request b1684120-6375-4091-a745-1c3d2aa2aa16: 'GraphUpdates' request to datawarehouse
Error --- Scripted Control (PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.manifest.json) --- Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Diagnostics.InternalHubException: ScriptedSandbox terminated during control initialization.
   at     Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Presentation.Controls.VisualStudioScriptedControl.ScriptedControlOnTerminated(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ScriptedHost.ScriptedControl.add_Terminated(EventHandler`1 value)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Presentation.Controls.VisualStudioScriptedControl.Initialize(IScriptedControlConfiguration scriptedControlConfiguration)
Error --- Service Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Presentation.Controls.ISwimLanesViewService implementation --- Could not create IScriptedControl.
Error --- DispatcherProvider --- Unhandled exception on DispatcherProvider.Invoke
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Diagnostics.InternalHubException: Internal Diagnostics Hub Exception. See log for more details.
    at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Presentation.Controls.SwimLanesViewService.CreateControl(ViewDestinations viewDestinations, IEnumerable`1 swimLaneConfigurations)
    at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Presentation.ViewModels.CustomViewsViewModel.OnActivated()
    at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Presentation.ViewModels.PerformanceDebuggerDocumentViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<UpdateViewBasedOnSessionState>b__1()
    at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Presentation.DispatcherProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Invoke>b__0()
```

Comment: Sadly, no. I checked for that file, but on this particular system, it already exists.

Comment: A repair of Visual Studio 2015 seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Enabled the logging as described in other answer and saw this error:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\EGKO838X.JT9\LMBXB9JW.4DO\4eeaf665\00d85bfc_f9cad101\WebViews\PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.manifest.json' not found.
```

But the file `PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.manifest.json` exists in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\DiagnosticsHub\WebViews`. Solution is to run Visual Studio as Administrator, no more *Internal Diagnostics Hub Exception*s.

Answer (score -1):

I found this error with a different cause. (e.g. assembly *DiagnosticsHub.CpuSamplingAnalyzer.dll* failing to load.)

During debugging the same message is shown in Visual Studio Professional 2015 SP 3.

Have logged the bug here at Microsoft:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3106402

A work-around/fix for this specific cause is provided [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567635/how-to-fix-internal-diagnostics-hub-exception-in-vs-2015-missing-diagnostics) related question.

Comment: Found more info on this exception here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567635/how-to-fix-internal-diagnostics-hub-exception-in-vs-2015-missing-diagnostics