# The diagnostic tools failed unexpectly in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, debug-diagnostic-tool

In the diagnostics hub output window, I can see the line

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

for one or more times.

Can anyone give me a hint where to look for this "unexpected character"?

Comment: Please try to enable logs for the diagnostics tools based on instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35299055/5225869). With the logs enabled you will hopefully see the full exception stack for the error which can shed some light on the reason of the issue.