# Visual Studio Update 3 - Internal Diagnostics Hub Exception How to Fix

Tags: visual-studio-2015, diagnostics-hub

After upgrading to Update 3 I'm now seeing the following error when launching into Debug n a WebAPI solution.  The debug starts fine but I would like to get rid of the error.

The error messagebox reads:

> Internal Diagnostics Hub Exception. See log for more details.

So I enabled logging by adding these registry keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\DiagnosticsHub\LogLevel  
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\DiagnosticsHub\LogDirectory
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35299055/155926) for more details on these keys.

The error I see in the logs is:

> System.ArgumentException: Manifest file
>   'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\NGZ8Y6KN.6LD\A7OEKLH4.L4D\1b2ef2ef\00d85bfc_f9cad101\WebViews\PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.manifest.json'
>   not found.

When I check the location where this file is supposed to be:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\DiagnosticsHub\WebViews
```

I can clearly see the file it says it cannot find.  I'm presuming that the location in the error message would/should be a copy of this "master" file in the VS `webviews` directory.

Anyone know how I might go about fixing this?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I have same problem but no solution. This is happening for only certain solution

Comment: Yeah, I just disabled the diagnostics in VS since I wasn't using it anyway.

Comment: I installed typescript for 2015 and that resolved the problem.

Comment: Installing Typescript works for me too, I think its reconstructing the MEF graph after installation that updated missing references.