# Internal Diagnostics Hub Exception in VS 2015. DataWareHouseRestWebHost error

Tags: visual-studio-2015

My VS 2015 has recently started to show me error on Debugging. "Internal Diagnostics Hub Exception". I have activated logging for diagnostics, but i cant figure it out from the logfile. Can someone help?

```
Debug --- Diagnostics Hub Components Loader --- Plug-ins have been loaded.
Debug --- Diagnostics Hub Components Loader --- Component 44d04ed9-f786-458c-93a9-7207a3cc52e1 (Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Components.LazyCollectorFactory) has been loaded.
Debug --- DiagnosticsHubPackage --- Visual Studio asks service 'Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.SDK.SVsDiagnosticsHubService'
Debug --- DiagnosticsHubPackage --- Creating service 'Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.SDK.SVsDiagnosticsHubService'.
Debug --- Service Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.IDocumentsService implementation --- New document was created 'C:\Users\PointLevel\AppData\Local\Temp\Report20170109-2333.diagsession'
Debug --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- Changing state from 'Unknown' to 'Created'.
Debug --- Document ('C:\Users\PointLevel\AppData\Local\Temp\Report20170109-2333.diagsession') --- Changing document state from 'New' to ActiveSession.
Debug --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- State has been changed to 'Created'.
Debug --- SessionsService --- New session has been created for document 'C:\Users\PointLevel\AppData\Local\Temp\Report20170109-2333.diagsession'
Debug --- SessionTargetsService --- New target added PerfDebuggerTarget.
Info --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- Initializing performance debugger session.
Debug --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- Changing state from 'Created' to 'InitializePerformanceDebugger'.
Debug --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- State has been changed to 'InitializePerformanceDebugger'.
Debug --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- Collectors count: 1
Debug --- StandardClientTransportConnection --- Connection protocol version: VS14Update3MicroUpdate
Debug --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- Changing state from 'InitializePerformanceDebugger' to 'PerformanceDebuggerInitialized'.
Debug --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- State has been changed to 'PerformanceDebuggerInitialized'.
Debug --- ConcordModuleLoadListener --- Concord Module Load Listener is loaded.
Debug --- DiagnosticsHubPackage --- Visual Studio asks service 'Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Collectors.CollectorService.SVsDiagnosticsHubClientEventHandler'
Debug --- DiagnosticsHubPackage --- Creating service 'Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Collectors.CollectorService.SVsDiagnosticsHubClientEventHandler'.
Debug --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- Changing state from 'PerformanceDebuggerInitialized' to 'SetupTargets'.
Debug --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- State has been changed to 'SetupTargets'.
Debug --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- Changing state from 'SetupTargets' to 'CollectionStarting'.
Debug --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- State has been changed to 'CollectionStarting'.
Debug --- DataWarehouseRestWebHost --- {"analyzers":[{"type":2,"clsid":"dca8b3ef-28c5-4b08-bafc-b072f8aa9277","localDllPath":"C:\\Users\\PointLevel\\AppData\\Local\\assembly\\dl3\\E4CLB8TO.4TB\\0D6WQKHM.YD8\\b1cf5283\\0070979a_f1cad101\\amd64\\DiagnosticsHub.CpuSamplingAnalyzer.dll","initialize":false},{"type":1,"clsid":"66edddf1-2277-40f3-983a-6ff57a433ecb","localDllPath":null,"initialize":false},{"type":1,"clsid":"66edddf1-2277-40f3-983a-6ff57a433ecb","localDllPath":null,"initialize":false},{"type":1,"clsid":"4694940b-046b-4885-9b7d-1fb0e8f2d54b","localDllPath":null,"initialize":false}],"dataSources":[],"symbolStorePath":"","symbolCachePath":"C:\\Users\\PointLevel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef.PackageExtraction\\TempSymCache","isJmcEnabled":true,"symbolLocatorServiceFullPath":"","portablePdbLibraryFullPath":"","sessionId":"910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef"}
Debug --- DataWarehouseRestWebHost --- Request queued. Controller ID: DataWarehouse, Action ID: 1, Session ID: 910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef
Debug --- PerformanceDebuggerDocumentViewModel --- Updating Performance Debugger view for document state: ActiveSession
Debug --- PerformanceDebuggerDocumentViewModel --- Updating Performance Debugger view for session state: CollectionStarting
Debug --- PerformanceDebuggerDocumentViewModel --- Done updating Performance Debugger view for document state: ActiveSession
Debug --- PerformanceDebuggerDocumentViewModel --- Done updating Performance Debugger view for session state: CollectionStarting
Error --- DataWarehouseRestWebHost --- Request failed (VS Package). Controller ID: DataWarehouse, Action ID: 1, Session ID: 910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef, Error message: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Det går inte att hitta den angivna modulen. (Undantag från HRESULT: 0x8007007E)","ExceptionType":"System.IO.FileNotFoundException","StackTrace":"   vid Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Hosting.IDataWarehouseHost.ConstructSessionAnalyzer(Guid& sessionId, Guid& analyzerId, String fullPathToDll)\r\n   vid Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DataWarehouse.ServiceModule.DataWarehouseHostWrapper.ConstructAnalyzer(Guid sessionId, Guid analyzerId, String fullPathToDll)\r\n   vid Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DataWarehouse.ServiceModule.Controllers.DataWarehouseController.BeginInitializeDataWarehouse(DataWarehouseConfigurationPayload config)"}
Debug --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- Changing state from 'CollectionStarting' to 'CollectionStartFailed'.
Debug --- PerformanceDebuggerDocumentViewModel --- Done updating Performance Debugger view for session state: CollectionStartFailed
Debug --- PerformanceDebuggerDocumentViewModel --- Updating Performance Debugger view for session state: CollectionStartFailed
Debug --- Document ('C:\Users\PointLevel\AppData\Local\Temp\Report20170109-2333.diagsession') --- Changing document state from 'ActiveSession' to Failed.
Debug --- PerformanceDebuggerDocumentViewModel --- Updating Performance Debugger view for document state: Failed
Debug --- SessionsService --- Closing session for document C:\Users\PointLevel\AppData\Local\Temp\Report20170109-2333.diagsession
Debug --- SessionsService --- Session for document C:\Users\PointLevel\AppData\Local\Temp\Report20170109-2333.diagsession was closed
Debug --- ApplicationPathService --- Hub application path is 'C:\Users\PointLevel\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\E4CLB8TO.4TB\0D6WQKHM.YD8\6dfa46a3\0070979a_f1cad101'
Debug --- Scripted Control (PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.manifest.json) --- Initializing the ScriptedControl with manifest file 'C:\Users\PointLevel\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\E4CLB8TO.4TB\0D6WQKHM.YD8\6dfa46a3\0070979a_f1cad101\WebViews\PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.manifest.json'. Base directory 'C:\Users\PointLevel\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\E4CLB8TO.4TB\0D6WQKHM.YD8'
Error --- Scripted Control (PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.manifest.json) --- System.ArgumentException: Manifest file 'C:\Users\PointLevel\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\E4CLB8TO.4TB\0D6WQKHM.YD8\6dfa46a3\0070979a_f1cad101\WebViews\PerformanceDebuggerSwimLanesView.manifest.json' not found.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ScriptedHost.Library.FileSystemManifestLoader..ctor(String basePath, String manifestFile, Action`1 pathValidator, Action`2 startUriValidator)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ScriptedHost.Library.FileSystemManifestLoader..ctor(String basePath, String manifestFile)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Utilities.ManifestMergeLoader..ctor(String primaryRootPath, String primaryManifest, NameValueCollection additionalRootPathManifestPairs)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Presentation.Controls.VisualStudioScriptedControl.Initialize(IScriptedControlConfiguration scriptedControlConfiguration)
Error --- Service Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Presentation.Controls.ISwimLanesViewService implementation --- Could not create IScriptedControl.
Error --- DispatcherProvider --- Unhandled exception on DispatcherProvider.Invoke
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Diagnostics.InternalHubException: Internal Diagnostics Hub Exception. See log for more details.
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Presentation.Controls.SwimLanesViewService.CreateControl(ViewDestinations viewDestinations, IEnumerable`1 swimLaneConfigurations)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Presentation.ViewModels.CustomViewsViewModel.OnActivated()
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Presentation.ViewModels.PerformanceDebuggerDocumentViewModel.<CreateMessageView>b__22_0()
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Presentation.DispatcherProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Invoke>b__0()
Debug --- ConcordModuleLoadListener --- Processing modules for process. PID: '7296', Unique ID: '887f380d-df93-47b6-ad99-a37782218a63'.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'mscorlib.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'mscorlib.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.Web.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.Core.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.Configuration.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.Xml.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'mscorlib.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.Web.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.Core.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.Configuration.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.Xml.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.Runtime.Caching.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.Runtime.Caching.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'mscorlib.resources.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'Microsoft.JScript.dll' to False.
Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll' to False.
Debug --- PerformanceDebuggerDocumentViewModel --- Done updating Performance Debugger view for document state: Failed
Debug --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- State has been changed to 'CollectionStartFailed'.
Error --- Session ('910275ad-c212-4cce-afda-d4393654dbef') --- System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Diagnostics.InternalHubException: Request to web host was unsuccessful: 'An error has occurred.'
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.DataWarehouseRestWebHost.<Request>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.DataWarehouse.DataWarehouseInstance.<InitializeDataWarehouseInternal>d__52.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Collectors.CollectorService.StandardClientCollector.<OnStartCollection>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Runtime.PerformanceDebuggerSession.<StartCollectionAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Sessions.SessionBase.<>c__DisplayClass51_0.<<ContinueCurrentTaskWith>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Diagnostics.InternalHubException: Request to web host was unsuccessful: 'An error has occurred.'
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.DataWarehouseRestWebHost.<Request>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.DataWarehouse.DataWarehouseInstance.<InitializeDataWarehouseInternal>d__52.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Collectors.CollectorService.StandardClientCollector.<OnStartCollection>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Runtime.PerformanceDebuggerSession.<StartCollectionAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Sessions.SessionBase.<>c__DisplayClass51_0.<<ContinueCurrentTaskWith>b__0>d.MoveNext()<---

Info --- ModuleJmcStateService --- Setting JMC user state for module 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll' to False.
Error --- PerformanceDebuggerSessionManager --- Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Diagnostics.InternalHubException: Request to web host was unsuccessful: 'An error has occurred.'
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.DataWarehouseRestWebHost.<Request>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.DataWarehouse.DataWarehouseInstance.<InitializeDataWarehouseInternal>d__52.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Collectors.CollectorService.StandardClientCollector.<OnStartCollection>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Runtime.PerformanceDebuggerSession.<StartCollectionAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Sessions.SessionBase.<>c__DisplayClass51_0.<<ContinueCurrentTaskWith>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Sessions.SessionBase.<>c__DisplayClass51_0.<<ContinueCurrentTaskWith>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Sessions.SessionBase.<ExecuteTaskAfter>d__53.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.PerformanceDebuggerSessionManager.<OnAfterLaunch>d__25.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link helped me, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38517169/3560234.

I believe I had the same errors in the log you posted, but after looking in the ActivityLog mentioned in that link it showed a Typescript support error.

**EDIT:** This worked for me when running VS as user, but running VS as administrator still gives me the exception.

**EDIT2:** I found the following link: https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=1293083.
**That there resolved my problems**, adding your user to have read/write permissions to vcruntime140.dll and msvcp140.dll. Hope this fixes it for you as well.