# Diagnostic Tools Failure -Diagnostics Hub - HttpClient cannot be null

Tags: visual-studio-2015, debug-diagnostic-tool

Using IIS Express, with Visual Studio 2015, Update 1, when trying to start a MVC 5 website I get the message:

> HttpClient cannot be null.

[image]

and then the site doesn't show.

I have tried the usual tricks of "closing, deleting the suo and reopening" or "clean & rebuild".

---

[This seems](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/92224afe-624a-4337-a523-3af3dcc8dda4/diagnostic-could-not-be-started?forum=vsdebug) to suggest that I should reinstall Studio, but I'd really rather not.

**What is causing this and how do I resolve it without a reinstall?**

I don't see the [symptoms in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070673/how-to-fix-internal-diagnostics-hub-exception-in-vs-2015-update-1), nor would I like to [disable diagnostic tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904929/how-to-disable-diagnostic-tools) like this question suggests.

Comment: The same here, have you found a solution yet and woul like to share?

Comment: Nope, no solution yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving to Update 2 solved my problem and restored the functionality of the Diagnostic Tools window.

[image]