# Why is Fiddler keep capturing sessions when I start web API service?

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I'm a newbbie to Fiddler, and I really need it in my web debugging. I tried to search for how to use it, but there is no much useful topics on this, may be due to its easiness!

What I'm trying to do is to capture the session from my Web API service. However, as soon as I start the service in Fiddler, it starts to capture a lot of sessions, and keep adding to its list, none of them seems to be what I requested.

I'm following a [tutorial on YouTube](https://youtu.be/GbKBcDX8DDQ?list=PL6n9fhu94yhW7yoUOGNOfHurUE6bpOO2b&t=375), where the tutor starts the service and issue a GET request and Fiddler stores just this session.

Is there any configuration I can do to get it working like that?

This is what Fiddler looks like when I start the Web API service:

[image]

**EDIT**

I used filters to block sessions from vshub, but still not getting any records for the service at all!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837163/visual-studio-2015-vshub-is-spamming-fiddler

Comment: I would suggest to not use Fiddler for API work at all. There are much better tools out there, for example Postman - https://www.getpostman.com/

As you develop your API you can build a collection of calls, which you can repeat very easily, you can save and share the collection with other devs if you need that. The point is that it's much better than Fiddler for Api development.