# Visual Studio 2015 community edition keeps posting to vortex.data.microsoft.com/collect/v1

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am observing strange behavior from my VS 2015. For some reason it keeps posting some data to vortex.data.microsoft.com/collect/v1.

I already uninstalled "Visual Studio Application Insights" extension. But I can still see arbitrary posts in Fiddler. I had no issue with VS 2013 and VS 2012.

Is there any way to stop this?

[image]

Comment: Here's a quick work around.. Map the `vortex.data.microsoft.com` to `127.0.0.1` in `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.

Comment: Have a look here for more information about the source of the requests and how to get rid of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452435/how-do-i-disable-vshub-exe-in-the-system-tray/32282345#32282345

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ReportViewer, there is a way to disable it:

<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" EnableTelemetry="false">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>

More details [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e6fd0eb7-2e6a-4818-a1bc-d18d3be89e73/how-to-disable-telemetry-for-ssrs-2017?forum=sqlreportingservices)