# Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe consuming loads of resources and crashing Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015

I am experiencing this behavior for some days now.

Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe goes bananas consuming resources and Visual Studio stops responding and crashes when a breakpoint is hit.

I heard this process is related to performance analysis but even if I disable it the problem keeps happening (even though it shouldn't crash VS neither debilitate the user interaction).

Anyone had the same problem and found a solution for this?

Comment: Over 4700 thread handles (and counting), but only 35 threads in "Process Explorer"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33153720/1032277

Answer (score 5):

VS2015 has a bug which allows the task named Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHost64.exe  to consume all the free ram so your computer pages to disk and slows things down. When I killed that task it had no adverse effects on my program, and reduced disk activity from high levels to low levels. The task may restart itself, but instead of consuming 10+ GB of memory, it then consumes about 40MB.  The bug only appears when running the GUI / IDE, not your compiled program.

It may be possible to programatically kill that task, haven't tried it.
Also, here is another possible workaround which can be seen at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1610160/microsoft-vshub-server-httphostx64-exe

** The following may require you have administrator privileges on the box ***:
1. close all instances of Visual Studio 2015
2. Locate directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VsHub\
3. Rename VsHub to VsHub-Suppressed

Once the above has been performed, Visual Studio 2015 will start noticeably quicker.