# ServiceHub.Host.CLR.x64 is not working anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When I hit to F5 to compile and run my project, every third or fourth time I get the message that `ServiceHub.Host.CLR.x64` is not working anymore. The message popups when it has compiled and the WPF application is starting.

Sometimes it pops up a few seconds after the WPF application is closed.

Screenshot(sorry, it's in German):

[image]

Does anyone know a solution to that problem?

Comment: ServiceHub.Host.CLR.x64 is working for Visual Studio.There may be some error with your Visual studio. What's version of your Visual studio?Do you meet the error when you click the exe directly?

Comment: My version is 16.6.5 
I updated it yesterday and repaired it, but it changed nothing

Comment: Can you check to see if memory usage is too large and leads to crash?If it is,this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368384/servicehub-host-clr-x86-taking-a-lot-of-memory-and-cpc) may give you some help

Comment: I need round about 9 GB of 32 GB. And that ServiceHub exe also doesn't need alot of RAM

Comment: Did you set the Visual studio with the suggestions on the tread which I posted to you?

Comment: I did the points 2 and 3 but I am not able to disable Full Solution Analysis cause the option does not show up in the settings