# ServiceHub.Host.CLR.x86.exe pegging a core, existing answers do not apply

Tags: visual-studio-2019, cpu-usage

This post [serviceHub.Host.CLR.x86 taking a lot of memory and CPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368384/servicehub-host-clr-x86-taking-a-lot-of-memory-and-cpc) says disabling analysis and "code lens" will make ServiceHub.Host.CLR.x86.exe from taking up gobs of CPU time.  With VS2019 (16.7) I see no way to disable analysis ... the indicated option only has "Current Document", "Open Documents", and "Entire Solution" as *radio buttons*.  Nothing anywhere to disable.  So while it claims to be a solution for 2019, it's not a solution for my 2019.

So far every search has led to that same information, either here or in a number of other places, rather than something that applies to my situation.

Does anyone know how to keep ServiceHub.Host.CLR.x86.exe from squandering piles of CPU time for literally no ROI?

Thanks!...

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but with me it seems to only happen after Visual Studio has been open with me debugging for some time. If I close and restart Visual Studio with the exact same files open the problem goes away.

Comment: Hi, @Ragnarok. I updated the answer in [serviceHub.Host.CLR.x86 taking a lot of memory and CPC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50635657/3944646) Have you tried the "Current Document" option? Although you cannot disable the feature, it will narrow down the analysis scope to only one document. Maybe this can solve the issue for you.

Comment: I do have "Current Document" set, on that very premise, but it would be much better to let me turn off what I don't use.  I also made a batch file that deletes a whole pile of VS processes that are associated with build and debug, which it leaves lying around all the time.  I run that when it gets wonked out, with VS just sitting doing nothing (with or w/o editor tabs) and that has helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing these options:

Options -> c# -> IntelliSense, "Show items from imported namespaces" and "Automatically show completion list in arguments".

I can't yet confirm whether this works for me, but I got it from James Rowell's comment close to the end of [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/606520/servicehubhostclrx86-32-bit-high-cpu-returns-in-20.html).

Comment: Sadly these are already unchecked.  (pout)  And I had such high hopes!  The silver lining is I have enough cores, this can take up one and I'm still ok.  It's more vexing than anything.