# Visual Studio hub-related background tasks won't stop

Tags: background-process, visual-studio-2022

When running Visual Studio 2022 (after upgrading from VS 2019), the four "rogue" hub-server background tasks listed below in yellow won't stop. What are they for and how do I stop them?
[image: rogue Visual Studio background tasks]

I'm running Visual Studio 2022 version 17.1.5.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368384/servicehub-host-clr-x86-taking-a-lot-of-memory-and-cpc

Comment: Thanks Hans for your suggestion. I did disable some of the Text Editor features suggested in your above link. It didn't help very much. I wondering if the NuGet packet manager is somehow involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the fix to this particular problem is to logout of Visual Studio 2022 then re-log back in again.

When I upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 from VS 2019, I was already logged into my Visual Studio "Hub" account. But somehow that "rolled over" login didn't sit right with the new VS install and Hub servers. Logging out, then re-logging in again cleared that problem.

I'm just guessing, but perhaps there's an authentication issue with re-using an existing login between major VS releases. If so, then the new install should have forced a password re-entry.